# DataTemplate-driven View injection with MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, memory-management, datatemplate, instantiation

I have a container view that looks something like this

```
<UserControl x:Class="Views.ContainerView">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:AViewModel}">
                <views:MyView />
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:BViewModel}">
                <views:MyView />
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:CViewModel}">
                <views:MyView />
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:DViewModel}">
                <views:MyView />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AvailableViewModels}" 
            SelectedItem="{Binding Path=CurrentViewModel}" 
            IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" />
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding Path=CurrentViewModel}" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

All my viewmodels inherit BaseViewModel so I turned my view into this

```
<UserControl x:Class="Views.ContainerView">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:BaseViewModel}">
                <views:MyView />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AvailableViewModels}" 
            SelectedItem="{Binding Path=CurrentViewModel}" 
            IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" />
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding Path=CurrentViewModel}" />
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

thinking it would instantiate just a single MyView and just rebind the viewmodel when ListBox.SelectedItem changes. Am I understanding this behavior correctly? Is this a preferred practice? How can I verify that I'm not churning memory as I switch between views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will instantiate a new MyView for each view model you use. If you want to reuse your user controls, you can set the DataContext property on each user control.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on Pavel's answer and clarify what happens when to the views when you change view-models is that a new view will be generated for the new view-model and the old view will *hopefully* be garbage collected in time.

The problem with this is sometimes we will have views that registers to some event in code behind (non-weak events) and this will prevent the view from being collected and you **will** have memory leaks.

Two approaches.

1. Any event subscription in view code-behind should be weaken (EventAggregator in PRISM) to allow garbage collection.
2. Register an instance of the view with the unity container and resolve it when you need to reuse it. Before you inject it into the region, just update the DataContext.

Hope this helps.